# Socket added in UE4 is too big- skeleton exported from blender

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

I have looked into some of the things that could cause this and after checking all of them, I still have the same issue.

The scale for both the skeleton and the mesh in blender have been applied and are at a value of 1 for all axis
The unit system in blender is set to metric and the unit scale is 1.00
I have tried both *checking* and *unchecking* "apply unit" in the export window

The scale of the character is perfect when I open and use it in UE4 its just the issues when adding a socket, the socket by default is giant compared to the skeleton

Comment: Hey, unfortunately as this question is not about programming per se, I'm not sure how likely to get an answer it is. You could try the unreal developer network, or the game dev stack exchange.

Comment: Your right, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Blenders scene units scale to 0.01 if you're using Metric by default.

[image]

Similar problem resolved here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/afvjrp/sockets_are_huge_and_upscale_everything/